# for..in loop over an Array iterates also over the prototype functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I've got a serious bug, which I've never seen before. First of all I've a simple Array:

```
var myArray = ["123", "456", "789"]
```

Now I want to iterate over this Array with a for..in - loop:

```
function mapData(list) {
for ( var i in list) {
    var item = list[i];
    if (item) {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

After calling the method with mapData(myArray), firebug shows in the debugger this:

> 1. Loop:  i = 0;  item = 123;
> 2. Loop:    i = 1;  item = 456;
> 3. Loop:    i = 2;  item = 789;
> 4. Loop:    i = compare;
> 5. Loop:    i = union;
> 6. Loop:    i = remove;
> 7. Loop:    i = select;
> 8. Loop:    i = contains;

So I think that are the prototype functions. But why? Any Ideas?

As I mentioned, I've never seen this before...

Comment: `for..in` is supposed to do this; it's for iterating _Objects_, not _Arrays_, so if there are any enumerable properties, inherited or otherwise, they will be iterated over.

Answer (score 4):

[Do not use `for..in` to iterate over Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#arrayNote).  This will iterate over *all enumerable* properties of the `Array` object and may not iterate over them in order.  There are two alternatives:

- [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (not supported by IE8-, although there is probably a shim).
- A simple `for` loop

Comment: Nitpick: `forEach` is a method of `Array.prototype` (and hence all arrays) rather than `Array`.

Comment: It won't iterate over _all_ properties; only _enumerable_ ones.

Comment: @TimDown I was considering writing `Array.prototype.forEach` but I thought it would be confusing :(

Comment: @ExplosionPills I edited the MDN article's title so the link shows the right thing now anyway

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a model of consistency on that either.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a bug, you're just iterating over all enumerable array properties, and a library you use added functions to `Array.prototype` like this :

```
Array.prototype.union = function(...)
```

The library can be fixed by making the functions not enumerable by setting them using [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) :

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'union', {value:function(){...}});
```

But you should never use `for..in` to iterate over an array.

Iterate like this :

```
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
```

or like this:

```
for (let item of list) {
```